# This code has really long loading times, how to reduce loading? (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, random

Okay, my code is a simple batch number generator 1-10, I need a way to make the code not take 1 minute per set of code. I use this code multiple times in my script, causing outrageous loading times of up to 5 minutes.

```
  :ans
set /a ran=%random%
if /i %ran% GTR 10 goto :ans
if /i %ran% LSS 1 goto :ans
```

this code has the random feature repeated until a number 1-10 appears. This takes a really long time because there are over 31.990 other ways it could go.
Please tell me how to fix this issue, with a different set of code or a edited version of the code. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just divide `ran` by 32,000? Or better still, use modulus: `set /a ran=1 + %random% %%10`.

Comment: Another way that works only to generate a random number between 1-10 (or 1-100, or 1-1000, etc.): `set /a ran=%random:~-1% + 1`. It is equivalent to `%%10` (mod 10).

Answer (score 0):

Limit the number? Like this:

```
  :ans
set /a ran=%random% * 15 / 32768 + 1
if %ran% gtr 10 goto ans
if %ran% lss 1 goto ans
```

The 15 is the limiting number, you can change it to anything, below 32767.

Comment: if you set the limiting number to 10, the `if` lines are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to limit the range of `%RANDOM%` by using the modulo operator: `%%`.
Try this:

`set /a botlimit = X
set /a uplimit = Y
:ans
set /a ran = %botlimit%+%RANDOM% %% (%uplimit%-%botlimit% + 1)
if /i %ran% GTR 10 goto :ans
if /i %ran% LSS 1 goto :ans`

You need to give X and Y a value. The +1 is necessary because otherwise the uplimit will never be generated (since you use the modulo operator). I haven't tested it so I hope it works.

Comment: with  x=1 and y=9, the `if` lines are obsolete.